# Force open deprecated Chrome app

Tags: chrome

I used to be able to "open anyways" a deprecated Chrome app (Authy in my case), but now it doesn't give me that option. All it says is that I can remove it:

[image]

Is there a way (e.g., in the developer settings?) to enable me to force open the deprecated app?

Comment: Chrome Apps have been deprecated since Chrome 94 - there was a policy to extend Chrome App support to June 2022 - that's a year ago - the fact that you have been able to run it since then was to give you time to find an alternative you could smoothly transition to

Comment: @JaromandaX When was Chrome 94 released?

Comment: After Chrome 93 and before Chrome 95 I would suspect. However, knowing google, it could've been yesterday - jokes aside, I'm not your search monkey, and why does it matter, one could infer it was before June 2022 which is a year ago, and nobody should be using year old browsers (that sounds more hostile than it was meant to, sorry)

Comment: @JaromandaX I want to know because it seems since this month in stopped allowed me to "continue anyway" and use the deprecated app.

Comment: perhaps the latest chrome (114) stopped allowing you to use deprecated apps - the release date of chrome 94 (some time in 2021) is irrelevant, with chrome 94 and newer, they were deprecated but can be allowed to run ... so in effect, you've had 2 years to find an alternative. The fact that now, 10 versions later, Chrome won't let you run deprecated apps, shouldn't be a surprise

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know: you simply can't. The facilities for Chrome Apps were removed from Chrome.

Anyways, Twilio Authy is no longer being distributed as Chrome app, either. Since it's basically a more or less state-less container, migrating to Authy Desktop should pose no problem to you.

To cite Authy's [page on the Chrome app situation](https://support.authy.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042973993-Authy-for-Chrome-App-Extension-End-of-Life)

> ## Authy for Chrome App & Extension End of Life
>
> …
> This means that Authy will not be publishing updates, fixing bugs, or making improvements to Authy for Chrome & Chrome Extension going forward. It will continue working as-is, until Google stops allowing it to be installed, updated, or run on your specific operating system.
>
> ## Authy recommends
>
> We strongly recommend that you immediately switch to using our [desktop and mobile apps](https://authy.com/download/) instead. These top-rated apps offer similar or better features for securely storing your authenticator account tokens, and are fully supported and regularly updated. Simply download one or more of these apps and follow the steps to transfer your existing account tokens.

So, that's it. Google stopped shipping Chrome app support, and thus your Chrome app stopped working. Follow the link there and use the recommended way of installing the Authy Desktop app.

Because you missed the window to run the old Chrome app next to new Desktop app, chances are you won't be able to transfer authenticator tokens. That means you will need to re-authenticate a few services when you need new tokens for them.